# Nestjs API accept calls only from https

Tags: api, rest, security, https, nestjs

Is there any way to make a nestjs REST API accept calls only from https domains?

Like block by default any curl or postman request, and accept only request made by my front-end client (https://my-example-domain.com).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem is to use middleware with the express defined for all routes.

First we will solve the problem of wget, curl and postman. These tools resemble browsers so the only way to detect them is by their names (User-Agent), so we take the name of the User-Agent with `req.get (" User-Agent ")` and check it with `indexOf` if these names exist and we transform them into booleans like the`Boolean ()`method and we check if the name matches one of the three and if we hit we return.

And now we will put the `https` protocol, it is very simple we only redirect the user to a url with https at the beginning but keep it on the current route.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let userAgent = req.get("User-Agent").toLowerCase();
    let isWget = Boolean(userAgent.indexOf("wget"));
    let isCURL = Boolean(userAgent.indexOf("curl"));
    let isPostman = Boolean(userAgent.indexOf("postman"));

    if (isWget || isCURL || isPostman) {
        res.sendStatus(404);
        return next();
    }

    res.redirect(`https://${req.headers.host + req.url}`);
    return next();
})

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Listening!");
})
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! But the headers are sent by the client and can't be trusted, so this method doesn't works :/